# Use different SSH key per GitHub repository on the same device

Tags: git, github, ssh

On my device, I have multiple repositories that can be accessed by different accounts.

Is there a way wherein I can use a specific SSH key for authentication depending on the GitHub repository?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bssh%5D+multiple+accounts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you want to clone `Repository A` and `Repository B`, but they can only be accessed by `User A` and `User B` respectively.

Assuming that you have successfully created an SSH key for each user, you can create a [SSH configuration file](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) saved at `~/.ssh/config` with the following content:

```
Host user-a
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user_a

Host user-b
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user_b
```

Afterwards, clone the repositories by replacing the `github.com` portion of the git SSH repo URL with the preferred host like so:

```bash
# Replace git@github.com:test/repo_A.git
git clone git@user-a:test/repo_A.git

# Replace git@github.com:test/repo_B.git
git clone git@user-b:test/repo_B.git
```

If you already have an existing repository on your device and you wanted to use a different account (a.k.a different SSH key) for pushing changes, you can create a new remote as follows:

```bash
# Create new remote for user B
git remote add origin_user_b git@user-b:test/existing_repo.git

# Push changes with user B
git push origin_user_b
```

NOTE: This will not change the author of the commit. To do this, you can refer to this other [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70982516/4772301) instead.

Comment: ssh config file line "User git" is not required if your remote url includes "git@..."